# How to gracefully handle DefaultControlFactory's CreateController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some links on my page for which the controllers are yet to be created. I have my custom controller factory like this:

```
 public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {

        public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            try
            {
                IController controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
                HttpContext.Current.Items["Controller"] = controller;
                return controller;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }

    }
```

This works fine as long as it can find controller. However I throws yellow screen of death if I return null from my method. How can I gracefully handle this? I want to redirect to some page along with 404 nicely formatted message or maybe show some message such as "In Progress".

Comment: starting point would be to catch the exception and log it instead of hiding it and returning null. at that point you would be able to explain what kind of exception is thrown and investigate best ways to fix/avoid this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding this?

`[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(NullReferenceException), Order = 1, View = "NotFound")]`

you will have to add a NotFound view to the shared views folder. Annotate your controller factory with this attribute.